# C# Httpwebrequest with proxy

Tags: c#, proxy, httpwebrequest

Okay so currently my program uses IP:PORT list of proxies from a .txt file, example -

```
proxy = new List<string>(System.IO.File.ReadAllText("proxy.txt").Split(new char[] { '\n' })).Distinct<string>().ToList<string>();
```

But rather than use proxies from a .txt file, I was wondering if it was possible to use them from a URL, I have a custom link that automatically downloads a .txt file with IP:PORT list, I wish to integrate this into my program & refresh/redownload the list once the list has finished or every 10-15 minutes.

Comment: It's definitely possible. Was that your question?

Comment: @stuartd to retrieve proxies from a url that downloads a .txt file upon following link

Comment: Easy enough, you download the file and then process it in the same way as you do currently. Nobody here will write your code for you, though.